# Django Ordering First Column Groupings by Max Value in Second Column Per Group

Tags: django

Given a Model in Django with fields/values as shown:

| Group | Votes |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 6 |
| B | 7 |
| A | 3 |
| C | 4 |

it's easy to use

```
class Meta:
        ordering = ['group', '-votes']
```

to return

| Group | Votes |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 7 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 6 |
| C | 4 |

How could this be modified so that the `Group` is also ordered by the max `Votes` value within each `Group` as shown:

| Group | Votes |
| --- | --- |
| B | 7 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 6 |
| C | 4 |
| A | 5 |
| A | 3 |

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Window functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) which will let you to calculate maximum per group for each record and later use it for sorting, like this:

```
YourModel.objects.annotate(
    max_per_group = Window(
        expression = Max('votes'),
        partition_by = F('group')
    )
).order_by(
    '-max_per_group','group','-votes'
)
```

But if you need to place all this inside your model you should use [Custom Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers), override `get_queryset` add Window annotation to queryset and use the annotated value in Meta's ordering, like this:

```
class YourModelObjectsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Manager.get_queryset(self).annotate(
            max_per_group = Window(
                expression = Max('votes'),
                partition_by = F('group')
            )
        )

class YourModel(models.Model):
    ....
    
    objects = YourModelObjectsManager()
    
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-max_per_group','group','-votes']
```

But, please, pay attention that including this kind of annotation in your model will lead to additional calculations on the database side each time you access your model (and this will be more significant if your model contains a lot of records). Thus, if ordering is a special case i.e. you need it for example in only one view or just in Django's admin, I would recommend to use `annotate` and `order_by` for those special cases.

Comment: The top part of your answer worked perfectly, thank you! Unfortunately, Django complains about "max_per_group" not existing in the ordering when building this annotation directly into the model.

Comment: I ended up adding a max_per_group field directly to the model, and overriding save() and delete() elsewhere to directly update max_per_group when somebody votes. Still interested in seeing how this would have worked with the annotation, though!

Comment: Did you change Manager in your model? I mean do you have `objects = YourModelObjectsManager()` in your model? Your models manager should be preparing this data for model to be able to use it in sorting. Please pay attention to the custom Manager. I've checked this and it goes ok.

Comment: I added that line exactly (and Django reported no errors on the line). Super strange that it's not working on my end -- ah well!

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?